# Бейджы в вордпресс

Tags: wordpress

Есть код

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'vs_change_sale_content', 10, 3);
function vs_change_sale_content($content, $post, $product){
   $content = '<span class="onsale">'.__( 'On Sale', 'woocommerce'  ).'</span>';
   return $content;}
```

Этот код выполняет вывод бейджика товара в Wordpress, как сделать так чтобы он выводил не On Sale а выводил разницу между скидкой и суммой , допустим мой товар стоит 5000 рублей а скидка 2000 рублей и надо чтобы выводило Вы экономите 3000 рублей. как мне назначить значения discount - price , я пытался сделать так и наоборот и выводит значение 0[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста )

Comment: В WooCommerce есть $regular_price и $sale_price.

Вы же можете с помощью этих данных решить свой вопрос, зачем в бейджи пихать это?

Comment: @eugene_v мне нужно чтобы клиент видел на бейджике наглядно , сколько он денег экономит в рублях

Comment: Ну так разницу высчитайте и выведите вместо бейджа